# Append and remove rows table Jquery

Tags: jquery, append

I have a problem with append table row with jquery, my case is want to append new rows to last rows in table, that success to append, but new row has appended on side table, how to fix it? i'am newbie to use this way. Example code in jsfield, Thank you.

```js
var i = 1;
    $("#addbutton").click(function () {
        $("#t tr:first").append('<tr>'+
            '<td>File</td>'+
            '<td> <input type="file" name="file[]" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle"></td>'+
            '<td><button type="button" class="removebutton" title="Remove this row">X</button></td></tr>').find("input").each(function () {
        });
        i++;
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t">
        <tr>
            <td>Id Gor</td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="Id Gor" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>File</td>
            <td> <input type="file" name="file[]" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td  style="width: 33px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 183px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addbutton" value="Add Row"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: do you want to place new file inputs under this first file input? in fact you are not placing it in side table, you are placing it on a new row on this same table so it shows from right side.

Comment: yup, i just to removing tr:first in jquery. thank to your information @ReadyFreddy

Comment: Your welcome. Also you can check this by opening google dev-console and look at html codes by yourself after your scripts. Good coding.

Comment: How to i saw google dev-console? i will learn. @ReadyFreddy

Comment: While you are on page, press Ctrl+Shift+J. On top menu, console shows clientside problems like javascript problems, elements shows html code and it's dynamic. That means when you run your script, it changes with it so you can see your html code after script. For testing, you can use your this code to see it's not adding it to another table but just to another row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is that you are using $("#t tr:first"), that block is getting the first Row() of the Table #t, and then you are doing append to it, to the row, so actually you are ending up with something like

```
<tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr></tr>
```

To accomplish what you want, just remove the tr:first from the selector. below is your code with that small fix working.

```js
var i = 1;
    $("#addbutton").click(function () {
        $("#t").append('<tr>'+
            '<td>File</td>'+
            '<td> <input type="file" name="file[]" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle"></td>'+
            '<td><button type="button" class="removebutton" title="Remove this row">X</button></td></tr>').find("input").each(function () {
        });
        i++;
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t">
        <tr>
            <td>Id Gor</td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="Id Gor" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>File</td>
            <td> <input type="file" name="file[]" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td  style="width: 33px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 183px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addbutton" value="Add Row"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: ah, make me confused, the solutions just remove tr: first, thank you very much :) @Gary